# Notation in numerical linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

The book says: compute an orthogonal extension s.t. $(V, V^{\perp}) \in SO(n)$. I don't understand what is $(V, V^{\perp})$ in the bracket. $V$ is of $dim(n \times p)$ and $V^{\perp}$ is of $dim(n \times (n-p))$. Is this just a notation for writing a block matrix?

I.e., if $n=4$ and $p=2$, then

$(V, V^{\perp})=
\begin{pmatrix}
v_{11} & v_{12}\\
v_{21} & v_{22}\\
v_{31} & v_{32}\\
v_{41} & v_{42}\\
\bf{v_{11}} & \bf{v_{12}}\\
\bf{v_{21}} & \bf{v_{22}}\\
\bf{v_{31}} & \bf{v_{32}}\\
\bf{v_{41}} & \bf{v_{42}}
\end{pmatrix}$

With bf being the indices of $V^{\perp}$ and non bf being the indices of $V$.
?

Comment: "The book" : which book ?

Comment: Instead of piling up your two matrices, write them side by side, getting a $4 \times 4$ matrix...

Comment: You should mention that $V$ is an isometry, meaning its columns are an orthonormal system, and you have to extend the system to a basis. The context is probably in connection with SVD and extending the small version to the large version.

Answer (score 0):

No, it means
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_{11} & v_{12} & \bf{v_{11}}  & \bf{v_{12}}\\
v_{21} & v_{22} & \bf{v_{21}} & \bf{v_{22}}\\
v_{31} & v_{32} & \bf{v_{31}} & \bf{v_{32}}\\
v_{41} & v_{42} & \bf{v_{41}} & \bf{v_{42}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
what you wrote would be
\begin{pmatrix}
V\\ V^\perp
\end{pmatrix}
(assuming dimensions align)